# SQL Join two tables without Relations

Tags: sql, database, join, datatable

I have different tables with the same structure, and I would like to join them by one of their columns.

The problem is that they don't share information in that column.

```
Table 1 - Type A:

Name | Value

Table 2 - Type B:

Name | Value
```

Resulting table:

(In a single column)

```
nameFromA

nameFromB
...
```

So far, I have tried:

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME, TABLE2.NAME 
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 
WHERE TABLE1.NAME = 'SearchQuery'
OR TABLE2.NAME = 'SearchQuery' LIMIT 2;
```

I know that my query is wrong because I'm calling more columns that what I want, but I am not sure how to join everything in a single column.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly do you need? My database is already built. It has 21 tables with 30 columns each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.NAME = 'SearchQuery'

UNION

SELECT TABLE2.NAME
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE TABLE2.NAME = 'SearchQuery';
```

You may want to use `UNION ALL` if you don't want to exclude repeated values.

To limit your result set you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( HERE GOES ABOVE QUERY ) LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Probably `ALL` too, I just can't put `UNION` and `ALL` next to each other in my posts due to firewall... :(

Comment: @GoatCO yes if he wants to get values repeated. what you mean with your firewall?

Comment: It's just an odd quirk with my firewall, errors when I post `UNION` next to `ALL` on SO and SQLFiddle, but not on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that they don't share information in that column.

If they don't share ANY information in the column you want to join, a join is `meaningless.`

---

A simple join would look like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 ON (t1.Name=t2.Name)
```